# Make regex into reusable function

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I wanted to make a reusable function for validation throughout my site. The following is what I' am currently working on. I' am stuck at where the pattern is not matching with the regex. Please guide me the correct way of doing this.

```
function match_str(str, pattern){
    mask = "/^[" + pattern + "]+$/";
    check = mask.test(str);
    return check;
}
```

> Error Message: mask is not a function

```
function match_str(str, pattern){
    mask = /^[pattern]+$/;
    check = mask.test(str);
    return check;
}
```

> Error Message: always returns false

```
//Usage
alert( match_str('test', 'a-z') );
```

Answer (score 4):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description:

> There are 2 ways to create a RegExp object: a literal notation and a
>   constructor. To indicate strings, the parameters to the literal
>   notation do not use quotation marks while the parameters to the
>   constructor function do use quotation marks.

Assuming you need to create the regular expression dynamically, you need to use the constructor - depending upon your requirements, possibly like so:

```
function match_str(str, pattern){
    var mask = new RegExp("^[" + pattern + "]+$");
    var check = mask.test(str);
    return check;
}
```

Comment: @RedVirus - thank you!  If this has resolved your question, would you please consider marking this answer as accepted to let the community know that this is resolved?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work